# How to upscale the dv 4:3 to dv 16:9 and maintain its quality while scaling

Tags: after-effects

I m working with two different footages dv 4:3 and dv 16:9. I wanted to make the project in 16:9 and upscale the 4:3 footages in 16:9 .. Is there any plugin or method that can be done without loosing its quality. I tried putting sharpen, bit and of saturation and antiflicker but its not helping, there is a pixlet vissible because of upscale of clip. Can somebody help me on this ...

Answer (score 1):

I will say this. Most people who use 4:3 footage in a 16:9 project will only scale up until the clip is even with the top and bottom of the screen. The sides will maintain an even distance from either side of the 16:9 frame. The blank sides will usually be filled in with another layer of video. This background layer will sometimes be graphics and information or even an upscaled, blurred version of the original footage played back in sync.

Check out this link: https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/8/1153004

I don't believe there is a way to convert your 4:3 footage into 16:9 without loosing any quality. I suggest a hardware upgrade.

Good Luck,

ND

Comment: Could u elaborate what u mean by hardware upgrades... M using dell precision t5600 with 2gb quadro 4000 and 8gb ram 1333.

Comment: I have to use DV tapes to record video sometimes, but I would not recommend it. Working with SD makes the post production process much easier when it comes to importing footage. But we all have to work with what we have. That is what I meant. Strictly my opinion, though.

Comment: I understand that  SD is much better than dv. But this footage that I'm using is from old tapes so I need to mix with that clips, I do have ex1 and hdcam but those dv footages is only clips I have to mix with it. Anyways thanks for ur help, I appreciate it.